# I start with the end

Tags: word, wordplay

I start with the end.
A sixth of a sixth

I end with the start.
A third of a third.

## What am I?

Tiny Hint

> Ignore the linefeeds.

Small Hint

> What does **the end** mean?

Big Hint

> It isn't a sixth of *sixth*, it is a sixth of *a sixth*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> (a) hat

*I start with the end.

A sixth of a sixth.*

> A sixth of "a sixth", is any one letter, and given we start with the end, our first letter is **h**

*I end with the start.

A third of a third.*

> Same as the sixth, except this time it's two letters, and from the start, so **a** and **t**

*What am I?*

> Putting all those together gives us the three-letter word **hat**.

Comment: THAT"S EXACTLY RIGHT!!!